# Follow BETA Inviter on Sign Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, invite, invitation, after-create

I have created a **BETA Invitation system** by following this tutorial. http://railscasts.com/episodes/124-beta-invitations. Users can also follow one another in my Rails app.

**How can I have the Invitee follow the person who Invited him on sign up?**

Currently, I am trying to establish this in my User Model using a method, but I am having trouble creating the method that allows the Invitee to follow the Inviter via sender_id/user_id.

This is the code I have used so far.

**SCHEMA**

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "invitation_id"
    t.integer  "invitation_limit"
    t.timestamp "created_at",                                :null => false
    t.timestamp "updated_at",                                :null => false
    t.string    "password_reset_token"
    t.timestamp "password_reset_sent_at"
  end

  create_table "invitations", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.string   "recipient_email"
    t.string   "token"
    t.datetime "sent_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
  end
```

**MODELS**

USER

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :invitation_token

  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed

  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                               class_name:  "Relationship",
                               dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

  has_many :sent_invitations, :class_name => 'Invitations', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'

  belongs_to :invitation

  after_create :follow_inviter      #---------- HERE!!

  def follow_inviter                #---------- HERE!!
    inviters = Invitation.find_by_sender_id
    inviters.each do |invite|
      self.follow!(invite)
    end
  end

  def invitation_token
    invitation.token if invitation
  end

  def invitation_token=(token)
    self.invitation = Invitation.find_by_token(token)
  end

  def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
  end

 def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy
  end

end
```

RELATIONSHIPS

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :followed_id

  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

INVITATION

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :recipient_email, :sender_id, :sent_at, :token

  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"
  has_one :recipient, :class_name => "User"

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  before_create :generate_token

  private

    def generate_token
      self.token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
def follow_inviter
  if invitation = Invitation.find_by_recipient_email(email)
    follow!(invitation.sender)
  end
end
```

But your models associations are not well defined. For example `has_one :recipient, :class_name => "User"` in the `Invitation` expects that there is a `recipient_id` in the table, but is not. You should review that.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, I'm a junior rails developer, but it looks like where you have `inviters = Invitation.find_by_sender_id` you should have something like this `inviters = Invitation.find_by_sender_id(id_of_sender)` where `id_of_sender` is the id of the person who sent the invitation.

The `find_by_sender_id` takes 1 argument (the ID of the sender to be found) and that is why you get the error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`.

Also for what it's worth, I'm pretty sure the `find_by_*_id` methods, where * is a model in your database, are deprecated. Rails 4 uses something like `Invitation.find(id_of_sender)`. When you call the `find` method on an active record model, it takes an id as a parameter.

You can also use `Invitation.find_by(email: 'user@example.com')` to find records based on any property you give them.

Comment: how would i define id_of_sender. I am currently getting undefined method id_of_sender

Comment: `id_of_sender` would just be the id of the sender of the beta invitation. So however you have that stored. Presumably, `user.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I am misunderstanding your question... I have a similar requirement, where one user can mark another as a 'favorite' user (i.e. users table has a self-relationship)

To implement this, I added a table called `user_favorite` like this:

**`db\schema.rb`**

```
  create_table "user_favorites", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "favorite_user_id"
  end

  add_index "user_favorites", ["user_id"], :name => "index_user_favorites_on_user_id"
```

**`app\models\user.rb`**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many       :favorite_users, :class_name => 'User', :join_table => "user_favorites", :foreign_key => "user_id", :association_foreign_key => "favorite_user_id"

  def is_favorite?(user)
    self.favorite_users.include?(user)
  end

  def toggle_favorite(favorite_user)
    if favorite_user
      if self.favorite_users.include?(favorite_user)
        self.favorite_users.delete favorite_user
      else
        self.favorite_users << favorite_user
      end
    end  
  end
end
```